# How to create mock Status object in twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j and developing StatusListener class and need a way to just create a 
mock Status object so I can test my class. I don't want to have to 
actually connect to the API while I am developing.

Is there a way to create a Status object from json string? I just want 
to download one status from Twitter, save it somewhere as a string and 
then reuse it to create Status object while I'm developing.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

One option is to actually create a mock `Status` object using a mock testing framework like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/).

As long as you know exactly what the `Status` object should return, then this would be one method which would not require any connection to the Twitter API.

Let's say for example that we have a `YourClass.extractStatusText` method which will extract the status text from a `Status` object and return that.

With Mockito, we could do the following:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

// ...

public void testCode() {
  // given - we'll mock a Status which returns a canned result:
  Status status = mock(Status.class);
  when(status.getText()).thenReturn("It's a nice summer day!");

  // when - exercise your class
  String statusText = YourClass.extractStatusText(status);

  // then - check that the status text is returned
  assertEquals("It's a nice summer day!", statusText);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let connect and download one status, then save it via Serializing

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/
http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html
http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/StatusJSONImpl.html

to create own Object use `StatusJSONImpl` class and feed constructor with `twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject` according to [constructor documentation](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/StatusJSONImpl.html#StatusJSONImpl%28twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject%29)

Comment: I can download a status from Twitter API just by using a browser from Twitter API url. It's already in a json format - so it's already a string. All I need is how to create a twitter4j Status object from a json string.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DataObjectFactory.createStatus(String rawJSON)` method.

See http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/json/DataObjectFactory.html for details.

Comment: All methods of that object are now deprecated

Comment: You can use in place of that `TwitterObjectFactory.createStatus(String rawJson);`

Answer (score 0):

ATTENTION this is **deprecated**:

```
Status status = DataObjectFactory.createStatus();
```

Instead use:

```
Status status = TwitterObjectFactory.createStatus(String rawJson);
```